# mongodb - find and replace partial string across various fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Say I have a URL: `aaa.something.com/id` that is found in several collections, in many different fields.

I would like to change it to `bbb.something.com/id` via regex (or similar) to find and replace only the prefix of the URL string.

The following:

```
db.tests.find({ "url": /^aaa\.something\.com\// }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.url = doc.url.replace(/^aaa\.something\.com\//, "bbb.something.com/");
    db.tests.update({ "_id": doc._id },{ "$set": { "url": doc.name } });
});
```

assumes that the field is always known to be `url`.

But in the database, The URL could be found in a number of locations such as:

- `content.photo`
- `content.media`
- `content.media[i].data`
- `avatar`
- `url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a wildcard [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) and then use [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) to find documents which match the specified regex. Once you get these docs you can write Javascript code for finding keys which match your regex and replacing them as needed.